# How can I read the message someone has reacted to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to read the message content of the message that got reacted to. I believe that the `payload` doesn't have a message object but does have the `message_id`. How can I even get the message? There is nothing I can use to get the contents of the message?

Specifically, if its am embeded message, I want to read the footer

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using ```on_raw_reaction_add```? 99% of the time it suffices to use ```on_reaction_add```

Comment: @LuM using on_raw_reaction_add alllows you to listen for reactions on messages that are not cached. This can help if the bot goes down

Comment: @AirKetchup Oh I see! I can see how that is useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer!

When using the payload from the [`RawReactionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent), you're able to get the `channel_id` as well. Using this, it means you can do:

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    print(message.content) # now you can view the message's content!
```

---

References:

- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)